# Detect if a Window is finished drawing and on screen (WINAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a problem. I created a Window in a thread. I created a mutex so that the Window handle cannot be retrieved via a function until it is not 0.

I also used a while loop to make sure the handle is not 0.

Thing is, the handle is never 0 because CreateWindowEx returns a handle to the Window BEFORE the window is even displayed on screen.

So my mutex and while loop fails. I need to know when the window is fully displayed and finished doing whatever it has to do so I can draw on it from another thread.

The Handle is not 0, the DC is not 0. But when I draw, it draws nothing. If I put a Sleep(100) right after doing CreateWindowEx and ShowWindow, the window is displayed and the image is drawn to it correctly. I also tried while looping IsWindowVisisble(WindowHandle). That also fails.

I don't want to sleep(100), what can I do?

Comment: Ehm, just handle `WM_SHOWWINDOW`?

Comment: What do you mean "handle" WM_SHOWWINDOW?

Comment: If you can do it from the window procedure, I believe it's `WM_SETWINDOWPOS` that it receives once it's all done initializing. Raymod Chen talked about it once, and I think that's what the result was.

Comment: Well that message is sent to your window when it is shown, particularly you should do your drawing in response to `WM_PAINT`. You can also notify another thread (e.g. via a message) when your window receives `WM_SHOWWINDOW` or `WM_PAINT` of course.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't try to draw on the window from another thread.

Post some data to the window and let it draw itself based on that data. It needs to be prepared to draw itself in response to a WM_PAINT anyway, and needs whatever data is necessary to do so in any case. Jumping through hoops to do the initial drawing differently is going to add a great deal of work and give you essentially nothing in return,.

Comment: I don't understand :S The window is created like: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bJh0Ceuf

And then I draw to it using another class from main. I don't want to draw buttons or anything to the window. I just want to use a Pen class I made that draws circles and rectangles to the blank window just to see how they look. I didn't want to have to edit WM_PAINT.

Comment: But THE correct thing to do is to add your drawning to the screen to happen within WM_PAINT - that's how it's meant to work, and that's what everything else in the system expects. Bad things (often hard to track down, strange, and sensitive to various kinds of changes in environment - run the code on a different type of machine, and it behavese differently, change the graphics card, processor, etc and things change). If you have something that takes long to draw, draw it to an off-screen bitmap, then blit the bitmap to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Note also that nothing will happen (the window won't be displayed) until you do something with the message queue; ie `PeekMessage` / `GetMessage` and `DispatchMessage`. And, as other people have said, if you're using the GDI to draw, you must do it in `WM_PAINT`. If you want to force an update, use `InvalidateRect`. Keep in mind there are a lot of gotchas if you try to work with windows created by other threads.